# What is the best way to break up a text file in java given certain limitations on what a valid string is?

Tags: java, design-patterns, java.util.scanner

I have been reading a lot of questions and answers about using delimiters and patterns but still having a lot of trouble figuring this one out.I want to read a text file that may or may not be jumbled up and pick the words out of it. So with input such as this

```
"the.dog,jumped over the hole@bob's house"
```

This would give me the following words

```
[the, dog, jumped, over, the, hole, bob's, house]
```

I would then do something with each word.

```
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(fileName);
while(s1.hasNext()){
temp = s1.next(String pattern = "no clue");
    //do something with temp
}
```

I feel like a pattern would be the best way to do it but how would I make a pattern that includes any variation chars long as it starts with a letter and ends when it reaches any of these characters? `. , * % " ( ) & $ ? < > ! - : ; @ #` or any type of `white space`.

I know I could do it a very ugly way with very crappy run time efficiency. Any help will be greatly appreciated or direction to another question that maybe of help that I haven't found.

Comment: I would suggest you to follow the approach as suggested below by other users. In addition, try to read this regex pattern from some external text file. This would allow you to experiment with the program easily (w/o compiling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
Scanner s1 = new Scanner(fileName).useDelimiter("[^\\p{L}']+");
while(s1.hasNext()) {
    String temp = s1.next();
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: So useDelimiter() is the best way to go when implementing a method like this, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think all what you need is to specify all your delimiters in the function `scanner.useDelimiter`,
here is an example that splits your testing sentence as you specified (using `. , @ space` as delimiter). You can add more delimiters as you want in the pattern expression.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("the.dog,jumped over the hole@bob's house");
scanner.useDelimiter("\\.|\\,|\\@|\\s");

while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    String temp = scanner.next();
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

If you want to ignore repeated delimiters e.g. "the....dog,,,jumped" you can use the following pattern as delimiter `scanner.useDelimiter("\\.+|\\,+|\\@+|\\s+");` , which only adds `+` after the delimiter

Comment: Okay awesome yea that is exactly what I was needing to do. I haven't messed with tokenization a lot but I'm starting to figure it out. Thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome. You might want to accept the answer that solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set delimiter on the scanner, and that should do the job for you.

```
Scanner s = new Scanner("the.dog,jumped over. the hole@bob's house.in land");
String pattern = "\\s|\\.|,|@" ;
s.useDelimiter(pattern);
while(s.hasNext()){
  String temp = s.next();
  //do something with temp
}
```

You can add all your delimiter in pattern string. You should escape (using \\) character which have special meaning in regex like .(dot), for details list of such character please refer [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple:

```
String[] a = "the.dog,jumped over. the hole@bob's house.in land".split("\\s|\\.|,|@");
for(int i=0; i< a.length;i++){
 String temp = a[i];
  //do something with temp
}
```

split() accepts regexps... use it...